# How to save a java object created from an representative, annotation based document Class, into Excel file using docx4j and Jaxb

Tags: java, class, jaxb, mapping, docx4j

Let me explain better what I want to do:

I want to create a Java class that represents how to create an Excel document, call it, for example

`class MyExcelDocument`

Within this class I want to define elements and data structures enclosed with annotations that allow me to use Jaxb and docx4j to save a `MyExcelDocument` object to an Excel xlsx file.

In fact, all the formatting elements of the document are properly defined in this class by providing information on how to build the Excel document when it is saved.

The purpose I want to accomplish is to create a dynamic structure that fits the data provided at runtime and produces Excel documents without having to make new implementations and avoid java classes proliferation on the project.

To do this, I want to convert Java data structures in xml format (precisely OpenXML format) through Jaxb and annotations and use docx4j to save them to an Excel file.

Libraries like Apache POI or JExcelApi were initially discarded because I do not know how to use them with Jaxb to convert xml to Excel document.

Any information \ indication \ suggestion about it will be really appreciated

Thanks.

Comment: This library makes the idea of ​​what I need [link](https://github.com/ozlerhakan/poiji)

Comment: Other library [link](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/reference/reader.html)

Comment: Other one [link]( https://github.com/takezoe/xlsbeans)